# Использую Transform.Find(), но получаю ошибку

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Ошибка:

```
Assets\Scripts\CameraRotateAround.cs(26,12): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Transform.Find(string)'
```

Код: `TheCam = Transform.Find("Camera (1)");`

Что не так?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find - экземплярный метод, а не статический. В твоём случае, предположу, вызывать нужно так:

```
TheCam = transform.Find("Camera (1)");
```

Comment: Да, это помогло, ошибки нету.